# Collect points (nodes) along the route via GraphHopper API in Python based on distance or real time tracking

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, graphhopper

I am currently working on the vehicle routing problem. I managed to find the shortest route between OD pair via GraphHopper API in Python. Besides, I managed to get the points along the route based on API attribute.

However, the distance between the points are not uniform (say every 100 meters or 500 meters). May I know is there way to do such settings to get points which are uniformly displaced along the route? If is related to the nodes stored in OSM, may I know what is the distance range between the nodes (in order for them to create the route)?

Another solution I am thinking is something similar to real-time tracking. Every 1 min, I check the location of the moving vehicle along the route. May I know is there any existing API (free) features?

Hope I clarify my problem.